# Making a release from selected commits

Tags: git, git-flow

By mysterious powers beyond human understanding a feature "X" not yet ready for release has been introduced and pushed into the "develop" branch:

```
a---b (master)  
     \
      c---X---d (develop)
```

I would like to make a release that would include commits "c" and "d", but not "X", knowing that at a later date "X" would have to be merged into "master" as well. What are my options?

We did consider rewriting "develop" to look like `c---d---X` but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, unless you rewrite **develop**, your only other option from what I can think of would be to **checkout c**, create a new branch, re-incorporate **d**, check that out, then create a release. Then you could just throw away that branch.

Comment: But in this case, after I throw away the branch, I will have no history of the release.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new branch `release` from master, and [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the c and d branches.

```
git checkout master -b release
git cherry-pick c
git cherry-pick d
```

Maybe solve conflicts.

Comment: Doesn't cherry-pick create new commits with new ids? If so, git will think I have a different history between master an develop which will cause me headaches in the future.

Comment: If you merge soon I think there will be no conflicts (easy to solve as will have the same line content or similar). Also as its release should only have bugfixes, so not so much change, I hope.